# Move all text of .php file to Array

Tags: php, arrays

I need to implement a multi-language system on my website. But, I have so many files with text in them and I need to put all of this text in a array like:

```
$lang['text1'] = "Example";
```

The biggest problem is because I have so many files, moving all of this text one by one will be terrible work. Is there any way to automate this work? Something like:

1. read the .php file
2. escape the HTML
3. add the text to array
4. Insert something like this in the files:

Comment: Take a look at the `gettext` extension instead of implementing your own, handcrafted translation system.

Answer (score 0):

(Warning: not the answer to asked question but pointless suggestion)

Some frameworks do use this approach, like Laravel. It stores language specific text in a different file.

Rather than just adding everything in array, what you could do is create a JSON, and then you could call everything from PHP or JavaScript at client. Though I suggest you put the text manually since even if you travel the HTML code and extract the text, you still need a specific key value for index (you could use id or class, but if you have indexed everything).

Answer (score 0):

Translating content in a web application or site is a problem that has been solved, I recommend using [gettext](http://php.net/gettext) over creating your own method of storing and displaying translations.